# PHP find missing numbers in array of hyphenated numbers

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, numbers

I have an array of numbers, these numbers are sometimes hyphenated, à la software version numbers. What I'm trying to do is echo "Missing!" or run a specific function when a number is missing.

For example:

```
$numbers = array('1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '8');
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
Missing!
5
6
Missing!
8
```

I'm running into problems with the hyphens.

For example:

```
$numbers = array('1', '1-1', '1-3', '3-1-1', '3-1-3');
```

Prints:

```
1
1-1
Missing!
1-3
Missing!
3-1-1
Missing!
3-1-3
```

Plus my code seems awfully long/doing too many things for what -- seems to me -- should be a simple task. Is there a method or algorithm for this sort of thing?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $numbers = array(
        '1',
        '1-1',
        '1-3',
        '3-1-1',
        '3-1-3'
    );

    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        if (isset($prev_number)) {
            $curr_number = explode('-', $number);
            $prev_levels = explode('-', $prev_number);

            if (preg_match('/-/', $number) and !preg_match('/-/', $prev_number)) {
                if (current() - $prev_levels[0] >= 1) {
                    echo 'Missing!<br>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }

            for ($missing = 1; ((count($curr_number) - count($prev_levels)) - $missing) >= 1; $missing++) {
                echo 'Missing!<br>' . PHP_EOL;
            }

            foreach ($curr_number as $hyphen => $part) {
                for ($missing = 1; ($part - $missing) - $prev_levels[$hyphen] >= 1; $missing++) {
                    echo 'Missing!<br>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($number != '1') {
                echo 'Missing!<br>' . PHP_EOL;

                foreach ($curr_number as $part) {
                    for ($missing = 1; $part > $missing; $missing++) {
                        echo 'Missing!<br>' . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        echo $number . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

        $prev_number = $number;
    }

?>
```

Comment: What's the expected output for hyphenated numbers? Or are you actually trying to improve your existing code?

Comment: What if the list started with `1-3-5-7` and then has `1-4` .. would there be something missing?

Comment: obviously, there is no algorithm for "missing-hyphenated-numbers". there are common building blocks and strategies. you have to think how they can be useful and put together in a way that solves the problem.

Comment: Jack: Yes. '1' should be considered missing, as well as '1-1', '1-2', '1-3-1', '1-3-2', '1-3-3', '1-3-4', '1-3-5-1', '1-3-5-2', '1-3-5-3', '1-3-5-4', '1-3-5-5', and '1-3-5-6'.

Comment: Karoly Horvath: Of course :-) Pseudo-code explaining such building blocks and strategies is welcomed.

Comment: Hmm I thought the Missing would be collapsed to only one. Also, how do you get from 1-3-5 to 1-4?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "get from", but 1-4 should be considered greater than and comes after 1-3-5. Like software version numbers: Firefox 27.4 would be greater than and come after 27.1, 27.2, 27.3, 27.3.1, 27.3.2, 27.3.3, 27.3.4, and 27.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list and for each pair you attempt to reach the second by applying a transformation on the first:

1. Increase the last value, e.g. `"1"` becomes `"2"` and `"1-1"` becomes `"1-2"`.
2. Add a new sub value, e.g. `"1"` becomes `"1-1"` and `"1-1"` becomes `"1-1-1"`.

*#1 can be expanded by increasing from right to left.*

If none of the transformations match the number is considered missing. In code:

```
$numbers = array('1', '1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '3-1-1', '3-1-3');

$first = array_shift($numbers);
echo "$first\n";

while (($second = array_shift($numbers)) !== null) {
    if (find_next($first, $second) === false) {
        echo "Missing\n";
    }
    echo "$second\n";
    $first = $second;
}

// attempt to transform between current and next
function find_next($current, $next)
{
    if (increment_last($current) == $next) {
        return $next; // first transformation worked
    } elseif (add_suffix($current) == $next) {
        return $next; // second transformation worked
    }
    return false; // nothing worked
}

// transformation 1
function increment_last($value)
{
    if (($pos = strpos($value, '-')) !== false) {
        $last = substr($value, $pos + 1) + 1;
        return substr_replace($value, $last, $pos + 1, strlen($last));
    } else {
        return $value + 1;
    }
}

// transformation 2
function add_suffix($value)
{
    return "$value-1";
}
```

This is not an algorithm, but a heuristic; it does a best effort at doing what you want but there's no formal proof that it works.

Comment: I think there are a couple of more valid transformations. But yes, this is a good strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer.

> Plus my code seems awfully long/doing too many things for what -- seems to me -- should be a simple task.

Right observation. If it's doing too many things, try to split up the task into pieces. Modularize.

For example: I see 6 `explode` calls in your code. You constantly struggling with transforming the input into a usable data format. Do a pre-process stage, convert the strings into arrays with `explode` once, and then work on that data format.

Comment: Fixed. `explode` is only called twice now, once for the current number, and again for the previous number.